# issues with printing messages after collecting them using sprintf

Tags: c

I have an example code in which I am trying to collect some messages in a buffer (torprint) and print all the messages on to the screen after collection. Once printed I want to clear the buffer and start storing new messages again in the same buffer.

The end use case idea is to print on demand but for now i am printing it right after i collect as proof of concept

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i,j;
char torprint[100];
char* pos=torprint;
char* fp=torprint;
int main()
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
        for (i=j;i<8;i++)
        {
            pos += sprintf(pos, "data entry number : %d\n",i);
        }
        printf("%s\n",torprint);
        pos=fp;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs but I noticed that I am loosing new data as well over the course. Can some one help me figure out what I am doing wrong???

output from above code:

```
data entry number : 0
data entry number : 1
data entry number : 2
data entry number : 3
data entry number : 4
data entry number : 5
data entry number : 6
data entry number : 7

data entry number : 1
data entry number : 2
data entry number : 3
data entry number : 4
data entry number : 5
data entry number : 6
data entry number : 7

data entry number : 2
data entry number : 3
data entry number : 4
data entry number : 5
data entry number : 6
data entry number : 7

data entry number : 3
data entry number : 4
data entry number : 5
data entry number : 6
data entry number : 7
```

Thanks

Comment: You're overrunning your buffer. You're adding 22 characters to `torprint` each time through the inner loop, for a total of 173 (22 * 8 + `'\0'`) characters on the first run. This is a problem, since the buffer only has room for 100.

Comment: So how do you resolve this besides allocating a bigger buffer. I thought that the "pos=fp;", will bring the pos back to the top of the buffer (i.e address for torprint[0]) and it would start over writing the existing data with the new one.

Comment: It will. But before that happens, you will already have written too many characters to the buffer just on the *first time* through the outer loop (when `j == 0`. If you really want to pile all of those strings into one place, you'll either need a bigger buffer, or a dynamically allocated buffer and something like `realloc()` along the way.

Comment: Assuming you change the `100` to `1000` or something similar, then you avoid the buffer overflow.  However, your 'diminishing number of outputs' problem is what you've coded; the inner loops runs from `i` to 7, so the first time it prints 0..7, the second 1..7, the third 2..7, and the fourth 3..7 — as you show.  So, you're getting the output you coded.  Either change the lower bound of the inner loop to 0 or the upper bound to `i + 8` or something similar — depending on exactly what you want as the output.